# How to get startIndex and endIndex from the selected block in gutenberg?

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to get the start index and end index of selection from a gutenberg block.

[image]

i could get the selected block by

```
wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectedBlock()
```

Here is the object returned by block editor

[image]

the object returned doesn't have any methods to retrieve the selection start and end in the block, the attributes property does only have the full text, is there an API method which could get this start and end index?

P.s: i could find startIndex, endIndex in props when i register a toolbar button by using this example (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/format-api/3-apply-format/), the problem i am facing is i couldn't get it externally

Answer (score 1):

You can use these to get the start and end of the selection:

```
var startIndex = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectionStart();
var endIndex   = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectionEnd();
```